# What does the term Data Buffer mean in the context provided?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

Consider the following article,

> NumPy provides an efficient interface to store and operate on dense
> data buffers.

According to my knowledge, data buffer is temporarily stored data in computer memory while moving, then why is that article using the term data buffer for the permanent data which we store in NumPy array for computing.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html - don't over think this.  It's just a contiguous block of memory  that numpy accesses with its compiled methods. You don't work with it directly.

Answer (score 0):

A quick selection of useful references:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

> An instance of class ndarray consists of a contiguous one-dimensional segment of computer memory (owned by the array, or by some other object), combined with an indexing scheme that maps N integers into the location of an item in the block.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html#numpy.ndarray.data

> ndarray.data -
> Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data.

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html